# Can't create Watson Discovery - only one per organization

Tags: watson-discovery

I cannot create a Data Collection in Watson Discovery as it tells me:

```
400 only 1 free environment is allowed per organization
```

which would suggest that I already have one setup, but I used the API to list environments and it shows the Watson News Environment and no other.

How do I clean up my system to start again?
I have tried deleting the service and starting again, but no joy.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is at the Bluemix Organization level so it may be that there is an environment under an instance created by another user in your organization. If you are not the owner of the org, you may need to check with that person to see if there are other active environments.